# Update only matching fields from custom type, Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists of a custom type...

This is the Class...

```
class StockItem
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Stock { get; set; }

    }
```

The Lists..

```
List<StockItem> CurrentStockList = new List<StockItem>();
List<StockItem> OrderedList = new List<StockItem>();
```

The "Current Stock List" looks like this...

[image: Current Stock List]

The "Ordered Stock List" looks like this...

[image]

I would like the Current stock to update with the 2 items on order

[image]

The 2 lists are called CurrentStockList & OrderList,  and i would like to use linq to update Current StockList with the items Ordered.

Comment: Perhaps a [mcve] of your problem would be better than diagrams.

Comment: I thought this would be clearer, anyone who knows what a List<Type> would be able to understand. Perhaps I am mistaken?

Comment: I suggest you read [ask].

Comment: Also note Linq(uery) and no Linu(pdate)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to make a group by :

```
CurrentStockList.Union(OrderedList).GroupBy(i => i.Description)
                                    .Select(ii => new { Desc = ii.Key, Stock = ii.Sum(c=>c.Stock) });
```